# Why is this Tensorflow gradient tape returning None?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow 2.0 and computing second derivative. However, tensorflow is returning `None` for `u_tt` and `u_xx`. `u_x`, `u_t` are computed properly. Variables `u,x,t` are defined before and are `tf.Tensor`s

```
import tensorflow as tf
# defining u,x,t
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tp2:
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tp1:
        tp1.watch(t)
        tp1.watch(x)
        u_x = tp1.gradient(u, x)  # shape (1000,1)
        u_t = tp1.gradient(u, t)  # shape (1000,1)
        u_tt = tp2.gradient(u_t, t)  # None??
        u_xx = tp2.gradient(u_x, x)  # None??
```

Any idea what is wrong in the second derivative computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following solution worked.

```
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tp2:
        with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tp1:
            tp1.watch(t)
            tp1.watch(x)
            u_x = tp1.gradient(u, x)
            u_t = tp1.gradient(u, t) 
            u_tt = tp1.gradient(u_t, t)
            u_xx = tp1.gradient(u_x, x)
```

It would be helpful to know why original version, as per https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/advanced_autodiff, doesn't work.